# Ollydbg gives output in which assembly language instructions in Intel or AT&T syntax?

Tags: disassembly, ollydbg

Ollydbg gives default output in which assembly language instructions in Intel or AT&T syntax ?

Is there an option to change the assembly language syntax ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default output is in Intel syntax. Precisely, Ollydbg 1.10 uses `MASM`, `IDEAL` or `HLA` syntax which are both based on Intel syntax. AT&T syntax is not available in version 1.10 but it is available in version 2.0

For Ollydbg 1.10 you can choose between `MASM`, `IDEAL` or `HLA` in `Options -> Debugging Options -> Disasm`.

For Ollydbg 2.00 you can choose between the `AT&T` syntax and the mentioned above in  `Options -> Options -> Code (Code options)`